# kafka java client not consuming - just hangs at consumer.poll

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am following Unified Log Processing book by Manning and it's first exercise is a simple kafka consumer in Java. The program when run just stalls where `consumer.poll()` is being called.

I am running this from inside the valgrind environment provided by the author of the book and it is available at `git clone https://github.com/alexanderdean/Unified-Log-Processing.git`

It has `zookeeper-3.4.6` and `kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1`

I have created a topic using following commandline:

```
./kafka-topics.sh --create --topic raw --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1
Created topic "raw".
```

`kafka-console-producer` and `kafka-console-consumer` are working as expected.

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --topic raw --broker-list localhost:9092
[2016-10-17 14:09:05,899] WARN Property topic is not valid (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
one
two
three
four
five


./kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic raw --from-beginning --zookeeper localhost:2181
one
two
three
four
five
^CConsumed 5 messages
```

The java code I am testing is pretty basic and just creates a consumer.

StreamApp.java

```
package nile;

public class StreamApp {                                                        

    public static void main(String[] args){                                     
        String servers   = args[0];                                             
        String groupId   = args[1];
        String inTopic   = args[2];
        String goodTopic = args[3];                                             

        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(servers, groupId, inTopic);            
        consumer.run();                                            
    }                                                                           
}
```

Consumer.java

```
package nile;

import java.util.*;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.*;

public class Consumer {                                                                                                                                                                                            

    private final KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer;             // a                                                                                                                                         
    private final String topic;                                                                                                                                                                                    

    public Consumer(String servers, String groupId, String topic) {                                                                                                                                                
        this.consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(createConfig(servers, groupId));                                                                                                                         
        this.topic = topic;                                                                                                                                                                                        
        System.out.println("Topic to listen for:" + this.topic + ":");                                                                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    public void run() {                                                                                                                                                                                            
        System.out.println("Starting  to listen for items ");                                                                                                                                                      
        this.consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(this.topic));             // b                                                                                                                                       
        try {                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            while (true) {                                                                                                                                                                                         
                System.out.println("Subscribed to: " + consumer.subscription());                                                                                                                                   
                System.out.println("Inside the loop");                                                                                                                                                             
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100); // c                                                                                                                                 
                System.out.println("After consuming");                                                                                                                                                             
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {                                                                                                                                            
                    System.out.println("Got an item from kafka: " + record.value());                                                                                                                               
                }                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        } finally {                                                                                                                                                                                                
            consumer.close();                                                                                                                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    private static Properties createConfig(String servers, String groupId) {                                                                                                                                       

        Properties props = new Properties();                                                                                                                                                                       
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", servers);                                                                                                                                                                   
        props.put("group.id", groupId);                                 // e                                                                                                                                       
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");                                                                                                                                                                   
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");                                                                                                                                                              
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");                                                                                                                                                                
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");                                                                                                                                                                  
        props.put("key.deserializer",                                                                                                                                                                              
                  "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");  // a                                                                                                                               
        props.put("value.deserializer",                                                                                                                                                                            
                  "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");  // a                   
        return props;                                                                                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

Libraries I am using are (from my build.gradle)

```
dependencies {                                        // b
  compile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.9.0.0'
  compile 'com.maxmind.geoip:geoip-api:1.2.14'
  compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.3'
  compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
}
```

I am running the code as:

```
java -jar ./build/libs/nile-0.1.0.jar localhost:9092 ulp-ch03-3.3 raw enriched
```

Output is:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Topic to listen for:raw:
Starting  to listen for items
Subscribed to: [raw]
Inside the loop
```

And that is where it stops. The `consumer.poll()` is not returning any thing and not getting timed out ether. Not sure what what is wrong here. Been splitting my hair for 2 days now, any help to get this working would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are using 0.9.x consumer API to consume messages from 0.8.x servers, which is not allowed due to 0.9.0.0 has an inter-broker protocol change from previous versions. 
Use the old consumer(namely Scala consumer) or upgrade the kafka server version to 0.9.x

Comment: Thanks! I upgraded kafka and now program is working perfectly.